# Either Join on row with matching value or join on null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to join on Column1 and (Column2 if there is a match, null if there isn't)

```
Table1
a,x
a,null
a,y

Table2
a,x,1
a,null,2
```

Join Result

```
a,x,1
a,null,2 
a,y,2
```

Comment: Please post the `JOIN` syntax that you've tried with.

Comment: Why `a,y,2`? Where 2 comes from?

Comment: Consider using a `LEFT JOIN`. @Mcnets I think the `2` comes from `Table2`. I *think* the OP is joining on the 1st and 2nd columns in both tables. it seems, also, however, they want to join on *`NULL`* (which is an awful idea as `NULL = NULL` will always evaluate to *unknown*).

Comment: In Table2, the row with the null Column2 contains the default value if you like, that's what I want to join on If there is no match

Comment: If you're using a default value (that isn't *`NULL`*) then provide that in your sample data. As I said above, joining on a *`NULL`* value is just a bad idea, and is asking for performance issues.

Comment: this query will be rarely executed so performance is not a priority

Comment: I've heard that before (it was a **lie**). :)

Comment: What have you tried so far????

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT
    T.Column1,
    T.Column2,
    N.Column3
FROM
    Table1 AS T
    LEFT JOIN Table2 AS N ON 
        T.Column1 = N.Column1 AND
        ISNULL(T.Column2, 'someValueYouWillNeverFindInColumn2') = ISNULL(N.Column2, 'someValueYouWillNeverFindInColumn2')
```

Comment: Not sure I recommend the use of `ISNULL` in an `ON` clause; it'll be awful for performance.

Answer (score 0):

If your a,y will JOIN on a,null,2, then so will your a,x thus you will end up with results like:

```
a,x,1
a,x,2
a,null,2 
a,y,2
```

I think the LEFT JOIN is what you want though. Something like:

```
SELECT Table1.Column1, Table1.Column2, Table2.Column3
FROM 
Table1
LEFT JOIN
Table2
ON Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column1
AND ((Table1.Column2 = Table2.Column2) OR (Table2.Column2 is null))
```

Here is the full test:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [Column1] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [Column2] [varchar](5) NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2](
    [Column1] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [Column2] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [Column3] [varchar](5) NULL,
)

INSERT INTO Table1(Column1, Column2)
VALUES('a','x'), ('a',null), ('a','y')

INSERT INTO Table2(Column1, Column2, Column3)
VALUES('a','x', '1'), ('a',null, '2')

SELECT Table1.Column1, Table1.Column2, Table2.Column3
FROM 
Table1
LEFT JOIN
Table2
ON Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column1
AND ((Table1.Column2 = Table2.Column2) OR (Table2.Column2 is null))

SELECT * FROM Table1
SELECT * FROM Table2
```

Comment: this is also what I tried but it duplicates the first row in table1

Comment: I'd recommend (instead) doing: `ON T1.C1 = T2.C1 AND (T1.C2 = T2.C2 OR (T1.C2 IS NULL AND T2.C2 IS NULL))` (where T1 is Table1, C1, is Column1 etc). Otherwise you'll (probably) end up with duplicates.